# Raspberry Pi proper connection to Pixhawk with DroneKit

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am having problems using the connection from my Raspberry Pi to Pixhawk autopilot.

I have followed the guide for wiring (serial connection) and installed the Pi with no problems. I am running Raspbian Jessie with DroneKit downloaded from github and built on March 12/2016. I am also running the Raspberry Pi direct (plugged in to USB and HDMI - not through SSH) and have used QGroundControl to set up my drone as a quadcopter.  Everything works, but when I connect through Python with DroneKit, I get spammed messages

> Exception in message handler for HEARTBEAT

and

> mode 65536 not available on mavlink definition

But I can request information from the Pixhawk and receive correct information back (altitude and battery voltage).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dronekit from the source to make it work, do this:

```
    git clone https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python.git
    cd ./dronekit-python
    sudo python setup.py build
    sudo python setup.py install
```